# angular-chart.js provider and injectors not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I've been trying to test out angular-chart.js for my current project, but I haven't even been able to get past the installation phase. Following the directions outlined on the [angular-chart.js site](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) (specifically the pie chart example), I added the proper dependencies for all of the components, but I'm still getting errors. Best I can figure is that there's a conflict with another dependency or that I called the injections in the wrong order.

Here's my `app.js`:

```
angular.module("datapoint", ['ngSanitize', 'ngCsv', 'chart.js', 'angular-chart.js']);
```

Here's my canvas tag in the `HTML`:

```
<canvas id="pie" width="300" height="300" class="chart-canvas chart chart-pie" chart-data="getPieChartData" chart-labels="getPieChartLabels" chart-options="options"></canvas>
```

Here's the beginning of my controller, `datapointController.js`:

```
var datapoint = angular.module('datapoint', ['ngCookies', 'ngCsv', 'chart.js']);
datapoint.controller('datapointController', 'PieCtrl', ['$scope', 'datapointFactory', '$cookies', function ($scope, datapointFactory, $cookies) {
```

And for good measure, here's how I call all the scripts in my `HTML`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-csv/0.3.6/ng-csv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Despite following the directions on the angular-chart.js site, I still get this error:

**Error: ng:areq Bad Argument**

`Argument 'datapointController' is not a function, got string`

Running into this before, I figured it was the placement of `PieCtrl`, but moving that around in different spots just creates different errors.

Adding `'angular-chart.js'` to the module in `datapointController.js` just makes the entire page go blank and creates the error:

**Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error**

`Failed to instantiate module datapoint due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=a...)`

And another error I've run into in my fiddling is:

**Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider**

`Unknown provider: PieCtrlProvider <- PieCtrl <- datapointController`

And I wasn't sure if `PieCtrlProvider` was another argument that I had to provide. In any event, I seem to be following the examples on angular-chart.js, only with extra added dependencies for other things on my site.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, similar to what Raghavendra was suggesting, you need to declare a separate controller for `PieCtrl`. While `$controller('Ctrl1', {$scope: $scope})` didn't work for me, creating a completely separate controller (in my case, within the same file) worked.

Example:

```
datapoint.controller('datapointController', ['$scope', 'datapointFactory', '$cookies', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, datapointFactory, $cookies, $route, $routeParams, $location) {

    //this controller's code

}]);

    //in same file

datapoint.controller("PieCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'datapointFactory', function ($scope, $rootScope, datapointFactory) {

    //code related to the angular chart

}]);
```

Hope this helps out anyone else having this issue!

Answer (score 0):

1. If your 'PieCtrl' is another controller, then you need to use `$controller` dependency to inject one controller to another as follows:
   `app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller){
   $controller('Ctrl1', {$scope: $scope})
   //Ctrl1 scope will be available here
   }])`
2. use only chart.js in your angular module dependencies

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work for me. I even tried calling a separately scoped controller within `datapointController.js`, like so: `datapoint.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope) {` but no dice.